# Is there a burning program that supports disk spanning?

Tags: dvd, cd, burning, blu-ray

Is there a burning program that supports disk spanning? This means that if you add data bigger than the actual disk (CD, DVD, Blue Ray) to the project, it will be spread across multiple disks.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a GUI program and needs some installation effort,
but if this does not repel you:

http://scdbackup.sourceforge.net/main_eng.html

http://scdbackup.sourceforge.net/examples.html

The docs talk mainly of CD and DVD. BD media are handled like large DVD.
I use it mainly on BD-RE meanwhile. My ISO producer and burn backend is
xorriso.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas